# (Java) Input validation not working as intended?

Tags: java, loops, validation, exception, input

I am trying to validate the input that decides whether or not the program does everything again or terminates. While it works enough that Y and N are the only accepted answers, it never does actually hit the catch statement - it only loops until Y or N are entered because of the while loop. I need to fix this so that the exception gets thrown for any other input, but I don't understand what I've done wrong.

```
public static String validateChoice(Scanner sc, String choice) {
    choice = "";
    
    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Continue? Y/N: ");
            choice = sc.nextLine();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid answer. Please answer only Y or N. Lowercase is accepted.");
            sc.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
        
    } 
    
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: InputMismatchException is not thrown by Scanner.nextLine

Comment: I found a way to accomplish what I'm looking for due to the answers given. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no error here, `catch` statement cannot be reached. `InputMismatchException` is thrown only when the input type is incorrect. For example, you ask for `nextInt()` but the input is `double`. You are using `nextLine()`, so all input is accepted.

Comment: I see. So I'm pretty much better off nesting an if inside of a do while for this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are catching InputMismatchException which is never thrown by the code in try.

```
 System.out.print("Continue? Y/N: ");
 choice = sc.nextLine();
```

See this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

So, to solve your problem, continue if user enters Y otherwise stop looping. It makes more sense to rely on a value to continue and consider everything else as NO.

```
if(Y){
   continue;
} else { //any other value 
   break;
}
```

Full code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Do some stuff");
        } while (continueCheck(sc));

        System.out.println("Completed");
    }


    public static boolean continueCheck(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.print("Continue? Y/N: ");
        String choice = sc.nextLine();
        return "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice.trim());//true only if Y or y is entered

    }
```

Comment: I will be needing to account for both Y and N in both cases, but I do thoroughly appreciate your explanation! You've helped a lot and I can see a way to do it with a do while and an if statement. :)

Comment: its a binary choice.. True or false. if Y -> TRUE , if anything else FALSE ... you don't really need to check the else part.. may be you are not explaining why you need that